# Objective-C: Double to NSString with x-many decimals

Tags: objective-c, string, formatting, double

I know that I can cast a double to a NSString with a specific amount of decimals like so:

```
double myDouble = 123.456789;
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4g", myDouble];
```

**But how can I replace the number "4" in this example with a int variable?**

Something like this doesn't work:

```
double myDouble = 123.456789;
int precision = 4;

NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.%dg", myDouble, precision];
```

Comment: you could try doing it in multiple steps, building up the format string as you go along

Comment: I would you do that? I just have no idea at moment :D

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: @M.J.K The accepted answer does not seem to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
double myDouble = 123.456789;
int precision = 4;

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = precision;
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = precision;
NSString *myString = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(myDouble)];
```

Or, if you want this in scientific notation, you can alternatively specify something like:

```
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle;
formatter.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = precision;
formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = precision;
```

It just depends upon what precisely you're looking for.

This also has the virtue of also honoring the user's regional settings (e.g. if in Germany, the decimal separator is a comma, not a period).

If you need to force the `locale` setting (e.g. this is for creating something that will be exchanged with a web service that expects the data in a specified format), you can set the formatter's `locale` (e.g. `[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]`). But when presenting results in the user interface, you always want to honor the device's locale settings.

Comment: Well, since it's only a German app I can be specific with the formatting.
But you're right, I'll better use NSNumberFormatter because of the amount of options

Comment: But I had to remove "minimumFractionDigits" otherwise it would show "123" as "123.000000".  Please correct that in your answer for other visitors

Answer (score 1):

You can use asterisk in place of optional width and precision specifiers. And set them as arguments

```
double myDouble = 123.456789;
int width = 10;
int precision = 6;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*.*g", width, precision, myDouble];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an optimal way of doing it, but it is *a* way.

You can do it in multiple steps

```
NSString *val    = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 4];
NSString *head   = [@"%." stringByAppendingString: val];
NSString *format = [head stringByAppendingString: @"g"];
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: format, 123.456789];
```

Or if you're really adventurous (for the sake of readability, don't EVER do this):

```
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: [[@"%." stringByAppendingString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 4]] stringByAppendingString: @"g"], 123.456789];
```

Comment: Do not do this, there are built-in that handle this. It also produces the wrong result: 123.5.

Comment: FYI - while this approach is pointless, it is better achieved with: `NSString *format = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%.%df", 4];`. No need to build the format with calls to `stringByAppendingString`.

Comment: @Zaph it's not strictly wrong, it just rounds 123.45 up to 123.5

Comment: @Electric It does not provide the result the OP asked for, namely being able to specify the number of precision digits. Hint, change the "g" to "f". Interestingly the other incorrect answers got voted up.;-)

Comment: @Zaph only reason I use `g` is because that's what the OP wanted to use

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the links in the documentation for `stringWithFormat` you will discover the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) which describes the formats supported. That tells you that a field width or precision can be an `*` to indicate the actual value is supplied an an `int` argument, so what you want is:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*g", intPrecision, myDouble];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was searching for :)

Comment: Try it with `intPrecision=5`, the output is: 123.46

Comment: Better to use `localizedStringWithFormat:` or `NSNumberFormatter` so the result is formatted properly based on the user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

```
double myDouble = 123.456789;
int precision = 4;
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.*f", precision, myDouble];
NSLog(@"myString: '%@'", myString);
```

NSLog output:

> myString: '123.4567'